# AngularJs resolve/retrieve a module by its name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As [suggested](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) I wrap all my services into a module, So, I created files to organize them:

myServicesModule.js

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', []);
```

serviceA.js

```
myServices.service('serviceA', function(){...});
```

and serviceB.js

```
myServices.service('serviceB', function(){...});
```

etc etc.

As a good practice, we should try to avoid global variables, so is there any way to avoid declaring a global `var myServices` by something I guess module resolving by name? I understand by putting all services into a single file could solve this issue, but I don't want to create a huge file.

Comment: `angular.module('myServices')` , without the second parameter retrieves existing module `myServices`

Comment: It is not encouraged to create modules for the service, controller, and directive layer. You will always have to load all modules anyways then. Split along the lines of functionality instead and put the controllers and services for a specific functionality into a module.

Comment: hi @flup, I got the suggestion from angularjs web site: Recommended Setup section from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module. what's your suggestion why not doing this?

Comment: This [Best Practices YouTube video at 34:19](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=share&t=34m19s): "Group by functionality / feature, not by type."

Comment: @flup thanks for your information, I will watch through the video. Interesting that the video and the angularjs website have different best practices ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter of module function (dependencies array) is optional :

If you set the second parameter, it will create the module (and override any existing module with the same name) :

```
// Create the module
angular.module('foo', []).controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
    // ...
});
```

If you do not set the second parameter, it will retrieve the module by its name and fail if module does not exist :

```
// Retrieve module by its name and fail if module does not exist.
angular.module('foo').controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks you, I did not expect the answer is so simple!

Answer (score 1):

> The [angular.module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) is a global place for creating, registering and
>   retrieving Angular modules. All modules (angular core or 3rd party)
>   that should be available to an application must be registered using
>   this mechanism.
>
> When passed two or more arguments, a new module is created. **If passed
>   only one argument, an existing module (the name passed as the first
>   argument to module) is retrieved**.

So this will work:

```
angular.module('myServices', []);

angular.module('myServices').service('serviceA', function(){...});

angular.module('myServices').service('serviceB', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need create variable for your service. It's possible tot do it that way`(in different files):
For example, file1.js:

```
angular.module('myServices', []);
```

file2.js

```
angular.module('myServices').service('serviceA', function(){...});
```

Comment: Thanks you, I did not expect the answer is so simple!